# Tanked the GRE Writing section, should I retake before applying to CS Ph.D.?

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, gre

I am looking into applying to a computer science ph.D program. I have 94% and up in the Quantitative and Verbal section but have tanked the writing section with a 17% (score of 3).

I am currently a master student (3.85 GPA) the program is ranked at around 55 in the US, should have great letters of recommendation, but I will not publish my research until after application deadlines. So I would have only one publication at a great conference but as a second author.

Should I retake the GRE?

Thank you very much

Comment: Seeking advice on retaking the GRE I believe can be on-topic here, but schools to aim for is close-worthy (no shopping), and your chance at specific universities isn't generally answerable. If you edit down your question to the 1-question per post guidelines I think this has a better chance of being answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difficult question.  Some universities impose minimum scores to keep their selectivity rankings high. However, some advisors won't care, especially given the discipline.  If you're courting an advisor, let him or her know and ask for advice. If you're applying blindly to programs, the score will probably hurt.

At the same time, as an advisor I would see such a score disparity as a fluke, and probably interview you anyway.

In the end, it's a competitive environment. If you think you can do much better, then definitely retake it. Study first :)